# python replace \n from text

Tags: python, replace

Here is a text file sample:

```
'15235457345', '', '\n\nR\n\nE\nM\nO\n\nV\nE\nD\n', '1445133666', 'nick', '', '1236500', 'git', '', '', '123face', '2015-10-18 ', '2015-10-23 ', 'name', 'great', 'sha', '\n\nB\n\nU\n\nT\n\nH\nO\nW\n', '1445123147'
```

I want to remove some pieces like

```
\n\nR\n\nE\nM\nO\n\nV\nE\nD\n
```

and

```
\n\nB\n\nU\n\nT\n\nH\nO\nW\n
```

I use removed and buthow to figure out the problem, but in real practice these are other words\timestamp etc.

Comment: Your example looks like a csv record. Do you want to remove whole columns?

Comment: You want to remove the entire string that contains any `\n` or just the `\n` and maintain the other chars?

Comment: You haven't made it clear what your question is exactly, please do this if you want to get some answers

Comment: if you want to remove unwanted characters, why not just use strip() on each string? again the question is not very clear...

Answer (score 2):

```
le = ['15235457345', '', '\n\nR\n\nE\nM\nO\n\nV\nE\nD\n', '1445133666', 'nick', '', '1236500', 'git', '', '', '123face', '2015-10-18 ', '2015-10-23 ', 'name', 'great', 'sha', '\n\nB\n\nU\n\nT\n\nH\nO\nW\n', '1445123147']
print [value for value in le if '\n' not in value]
```

Output:

```
['15235457345', '', '1445133666', 'nick', '', '1236500', 'git', '', '', '123face', '2015-10-18 ', '2015-10-23 ', 'name', 'great', 'sha', '1445123147']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='15235457345', '', '\n\nR\n\nE\nM\nO\n\nV\nE\nD\n', '1445133666', 'nick', '', '1236500', 'git', '', '', '123face', '2015-10-18 ', '2015-10-23 ', 'name', 'great', 'sha', '\n\nB\n\nU\n\nT\n\nH\nO\nW\n', '1445123147'

for i in range(0,len(s)):
    print s[i].replace('\n','')
```

Output:

```
15235457345

REMOVED
1445133666
nick

1236500
git


123face
2015-10-18 
2015-10-23 
name
great
sha
BUTHOW
1445123147
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.